# Magento 404 Page redirect to home page in Nginx

Tags: magento-1.8, nginx, 404-page

We work on a Magento website and recently we have created a customer 404 page basically a new CMS page and set it as CMS no route page in configuration.

This is working fine on my local system and website replica (Running through a subdomain) but not on main website.

If we type a wrong CMS page url then it redirect to home page. If we type wrong sub category url then it redirect to parent category page e.g. /men/clothing/jeansss.html redirect to /men/clothing.html and /men/clothings.html redirect to /men.html and /mens.html redirect to home page.

Please help me on this. Is there anyone who have faced the same issue?

Comment: just check if you have specific rewrites, something like `try_files` or `if (-f $request_filename)`

Comment: Yes we have a line like this " if (!-e $request_filename) { rewrite / /index.php last; } ## Catch 404s that try_files miss".

Comment: We also have another line try_files $uri $uri/ @handler; ## If missing pass the URI to Magento's front handler. Please let us know if we need to do any change in these lines.

Comment: Hi, we are still facing this problem. Please help in case anyone experiencing the same issue.

Comment: thats what im talking about, you either intercept 404 errors in nginx or magento, or you just need to use magento 404 page as nginx custom 404 page.  `http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpCoreModule#error_page`

Comment: Thanks ADM for your suggestion. I just to manage 404 page from Magento only. Recently we have setup a replica of website on server on a subdomain and 404 page is working there but not with main domain.

Answer (score 2):

Magento has a built in function for where to send 404s to, it is likely this is configured to send them to the home page.

In the admin panel, goto System -> Configuration then select Web under General on the left, and open up the tab Default Pages

There should be a CMS No Route Page, which is likely currently set to the Home Page, Change this to your desired CMS page and you should be fine. You may need to clear the cache before you see this change take effect.

Comment: We have already done this. But still it is redirecting to home page.